# Replacing not in with left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

Im looking to correct my syntax for a left join in a mySQL database.  My query runs but is very slow and I'm not sure if my left join is correct.  I'm needing to select the consumer_id against previous successes.  In order to check those previous successes I must left join on the records table and mappings table to link the mapping id to the consumer id which only exists in the event_queue table.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

1st query:

```
SELECT  
CEQ.consumer_ID
, F.client_license_ID
, F.footprint_ID
, F.event_token_ID
, EM.event_ID
, EM.mapping_ID em_ID
, EM.export_value campaign_number
, EM.export_value_2 sequence_number
, EM.export_value_3 campaign_number_2
, EM.export_value_4 sequence_number_2
, EM.export_value_5 ffs_event_id
, EM.export_value_6
, EM.export_value_7
, EM.export_value_8
, EM.export_value_9
, EM.export_value_10

FROM data_transfer.Event_Mappings EM
JOIN data_transfer.Event_Queue CEQ ON CEQ.event_ID = EM.event_ID
JOIN Footprints F ON CEQ.consumer_ID = F.consumer_ID
LEFT JOIN efn_data_transfer.CRM_Records LCR ON LCR.consumer_ID = CEQ.consumer_ID
WHERE EM.data_transfer_ID = 24
AND EM.mode = 'production'
AND EM.active_flag = 1
AND F.sample_flag = 0
AND CEQ.modify_DTM > (SELECT last_transfer FROM (SELECT CAST(DATE_SUB(start,INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS CHAR) last_transfer
FROM data_transfer.DT_Runs DTR
WHERE DTR.data_transfer_ID = 24
AND DTR.result = 1
AND DTR.mode = 'production'
ORDER BY DTR.dt_run_ID DESC
LIMIT 1)as D 
) 
GROUP BY
CEQ.consumer_ID
, F.client_license_ID
, F.footprint_ID
, F.event_token_ID
, EM.event_ID
, EM.mapping_ID 
, EM.export_value 
, EM.export_value_2 
, EM.export_value_3 
, EM.export_value_4 
, EM.export_value_5 
, EM.export_value_6
, EM.export_value_7
, EM.export_value_8
, EM.export_value_9
, EM.export_value_10

ORDER BY F.client_license_ID, CEQ.consumer_ID, EM.mapping_ID, CEQ.modify_DTM;
```

Combined Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CEQ.consumer_ID AS CHAR) AS consumer_ID_1
FROM data_transfer.Event_Queue CEQ
WHERE 0=0
AND CEQ.consumer_ID NOT IN (SELECT RR.consumer_ID FROM data_transfer.Records RR
  JOIN data_transfer.Event_Mappings EM ON RR.event_mapping_ID = EM.event_mapping_ID
  WHERE 0=0
  AND RR.failure_code = 0
  AND RR.mode = 'production'
  AND RR.`ignore` = 0
  AND RR.response_code = 'SUCCESS'
  AND RR.data_transfer_ID = 24
  AND RR.consumer_ID = ?
  AND EM.event_ID = ?
)
AND CEQ.consumer_ID = ?
```

Attempted Query:

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT
EM.event_ID
, F.footprint_ID
, F.event_token_ID
FROM data_transfer.Event_Mappings EM
JOIN data_transfer.Event_Queue CEQ ON CEQ.event_ID = EM.event_ID
JOIN Footprints F ON CEQ.consumer_ID = F.consumer_ID
LEFT JOIN efn_data_transfer.CRM_Records LCR ON LCR.consumer_ID = CEQ.consumer_ID

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT CEQ.consumer_ID AS consumer_ID_1
FROM data_transfer.Event_Queue CEQ, data_transfer.Records RR
LEFT JOIN  data_transfer.Mappings EM ON EM.mapping_id = RR.mapping_id
WHERE RR.consumer_id = CEQ.consumer_id
  AND RR.failure_code = 0
  AND RR.mode = 'production'
  AND RR.`ignore` = 0
  AND RR.response_code = 'SUCCESS'
  AND RR.data_transfer_ID = 24

) AS RECORDS ON CEQ.consumer_id

WHERE EM.data_transfer_ID = 24
AND EM.mode = 'production'
AND EM.active_flag = 1
AND F.sample_flag = 0
AND CEQ.modify_DTM > (SELECT last_transfer FROM (SELECT CAST(DATE_SUB(start,INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS CHAR) last_transfer
FROM data_transfer.DT_Runs DTR
WHERE DTR.data_transfer_ID = 24
AND DTR.result = 1
AND DTR.mode = 'production'
ORDER BY DTR.dt_run_ID DESC
LIMIT 1) AS D 
) 
GROUP BY
CEQ.consumer_ID
, F.client_license_ID
, F.footprint_ID
, F.event_token_ID
, EM.event_ID
, EM.mapping_ID 
, EM.export_value 
, EM.export_value_2 
, EM.export_value_3 
, EM.export_value_4 
, EM.export_value_5 
, EM.export_value_6
, EM.export_value_7
, EM.export_value_8
, EM.export_value_9
, EM.export_value_10

ORDER BY F.client_license_ID, CEQ.consumer_ID, EM.mapping_ID, CEQ.modify_DTM;
```

Comment: Try to eliminate your dependent sub query in where clause and rewrite your query using joins only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery does not rely on anything specific and can be it's own query as part of the "FROM" clause.  Since it is only returning 1 row via the limit, you don't need to JOIN it to anything.  This results in just the date computed value once for the remainder of the query.

As for your tables, I offer the following suggested indexes to help as optimizing against the respective WHERE and JOIN criteria.

```
Table           Index
Event_Mappings  ( data_transfer_id, active_flag, mode, Event_id )
Event_Queue     ( Event_id, consumer_ID, modify_DTM )
Footprints      ( consumer_ID, sample_flag, client_license_ID )
DT_Runs         ( data_transfer_id, result, mode, dt_run_id, start )
Records         ( data_transfer_id, failure_code, mode, ignore, response_code )

SELECT DISTINCT
      CEQ.consumer_ID, 
      F.client_license_ID, 
      F.footprint_ID, 
      F.event_token_ID, 
      EM.event_ID, 
      EM.mapping_ID em_ID, 
      EM.export_value campaign_number, 
      EM.export_value_2 sequence_number, 
      EM.export_value_3 campaign_number_2, 
      EM.export_value_4 sequence_number_2, 
      EM.export_value_5 ffs_event_id, 
      EM.export_value_6, 
      EM.export_value_7, 
      EM.export_value_8, 
      EM.export_value_9, 
      EM.export_value_10
   FROM 
      data_transfer.Event_Mappings EM
         JOIN data_transfer.Event_Queue CEQ 
            ON EM.event_ID = CEQ.event_ID 
            JOIN Footprints F 
               ON CEQ.consumer_ID = F.consumer_ID
              AND F.sample_flag = 0
            LEFT JOIN efn_data_transfer.CRM_Records LCR 
               ON CEQ.consumer_ID = LCR.consumer_ID
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                              CEQ.consumer_ID AS consumer_ID_1
                           FROM 
                              data_transfer.Records RR
                                 LEFT JOIN data_transfer.Mappings EM 
                                    ON RR.mapping_id = EM.mapping_id 
                                 JOIN data_transfer.Event_Queue CEQ
                                    ON RR.consumer_id = CEQ.consumer_id
                           WHERE 
                                  RR.data_transfer_ID = 24
                              AND RR.failure_code = 0
                              AND RR.mode = 'production'
                              AND RR.`ignore` = 0
                              AND RR.response_code = 'SUCCESS' ) AS RECORDS 
               ON CEQ.consumer_id = RECORDS.consumer_id_1,
      ( SELECT 
              CAST(DATE_SUB(start,INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS CHAR) last_transfer
           FROM 
              data_transfer.DT_Runs DTR
           WHERE 
                  DTR.data_transfer_ID = 24
              AND DTR.result = 1
              AND DTR.mode = 'production'
           ORDER BY 
              DTR.dt_run_ID DESC 
           LIMIT 1 ) as LT
   WHERE 
          EM.data_transfer_ID = 24
      AND EM.mode = 'production'
      AND EM.active_flag = 1
      AND CEQ.modify_DTM > LT.Last_Transfer
      AND RECORDS.consumer_id_1 IS NULL
   ORDER BY 
      F.client_license_ID, 
      CEQ.consumer_ID, 
      EM.mapping_ID, 
      CEQ.modify_DTM;
```

Revised to include your RECORDS alias left-joined... Then, looking for the RECORDS "consumer_id_1" column being NULL (thus NOT IN)